# How to send form data in a fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I wrote a simple nodejs server to allow a local web page to proxy remote data by $.ajax call) and avoid CORS problems.
Everything is working but the last call: this one is a POST call with a number of form input data that I need to turn to the remote server.
The request is received by the server but it doesn't receive the form data.

The code is:

```
function saveDati(req, resp) {
    var url = "https://www.xyz.xyz/web/call?portlet.action=saveDataForm"

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: req.body,
    })
    .then((resp1) => {
        return resp1.text()
    })
    .then((risp2) => {
        console.log(risp2)
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        resp.send(risp2);
        console.log(".. sent")
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

How can I send the form data correctly?

Comment: Always refer to MDN docs for this - [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Scroll down to `Uploading a File`. Note: you can use FormData for a fetch request with or without a File, so don't let the "Uploading a File" thing spook you.

Comment: Are you using express for API?
From question i understand you are not able to send form request to `https://www.xyz.xyz/web/call?portlet.action=saveDataForm` ?

Comment: Adam: in the example they feed by FormData() object. In my case I receive the request from the page (by app.post(xxx)) that already contains the form data in req.body. Do I need to create the FormData object enumerating the req.body content?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a header like this

```
function saveDati(req, resp) {
    var url = "https://www.xyz.xyz/web/call?portlet.action=saveDataForm"

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: req.body,
    })
    .then((resp1) => {
        return resp1.text()
    })
    .then((risp2) => {
        console.log(risp2)
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        resp.send(risp2);
        console.log(".. sent")
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```